# How to add custom data as calculated property in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a csv file with 4 custom named columns where 3 of them are populated with properties from Active Directory and the 4th one with custom data because it’s not available in Active Directory. So far, I've managed to get 3 properties from AD and store them as calculated properties but I have no idea how to add the 4th row with the static data.
The static data that I want to import to the cvs file is in another file but I don’t mind to create it on the fly in the script, for example as an array.

Here is my code so far. As you can see I’m searching for accounts only with job title property and extracting information about their department, Description, samaccountname and display them as calculated properties GroupID, GroupName and ManagerID

```
Get-AdUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "True" ) -and (title -like '*')} -Properties title,Description,department |select -Property @{Name='GroupID'; Expression={$_.department}}, @{Name='GroupName'; Expression={$_.Description}},@{Name='ManagerID'; Expression= {$_.samaccountname}}
```

The output looks like this.

```
GroupID GroupName                                                        ManagerID
------- ---------                                                        ---------
Z0      Division blabla (Z0)                                             fakeID1
ZR0     Department blabla (SR)                                           fakeID2
ZR5     Unit bla bla (ZR5)                                               fakeID3
ZK2     Unit bla bla (ZK2)                                               fakeID4
OB2     Unit bla bla (OB2)                                               fakeID5
```

What I can’t do is to take custom data "N,NR0,NR0,N,NV0,NV0,NV0,Z0,ZK0,OB0, O"and put it in a new column with a name "ParentGroup". The "parentGroup" is the information about which department is a parent to another department and it’s not stored in AD.
I would like to see the result like the output beyond.

```
GroupID GroupName                   ParentID                         ManagerID
------- ---------                   --------                         ---------
Z0      Division blabla (Z0)        Z                                fakeID1
ZR0     Department blabla (ZR0)     Z                                fakeID2
ZR5     Unit bla bla (ZR5)          ZR0                              fakeID3
ZK2     Unit bla bla (ZK2)          ZK0                              fakeID4
OB2     Unit bla bla (OB2)          OB0                              fakeID5
```

I really appreciate if someone could help me.
Best regards!

Comment: "and it’s not stored in AD." - well, where _is it_ stored then? PowerShell can't just guess :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of parent-child relationships, you can load the data into a hashtable and use that to look up the parent id from inside the property expression:

```
# load data, this could as well be done from an external csv file
$relationships = @'
parent,child
Z,Z0
Z,ZR0
ZR0,ZR5
ZK0,ZK2
OB2,OB0
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv

# create and populate hashtable
$parentIDs = @{}
$relationships |ForEach-Object {
  $parentIDs[$_.child] = $_.parent
}
```

And then in your calculated property:

```
... |Select -Property @{Name='ParentID';Expression={$parentIDs[$_.department]}},...
```